# Avoid scene monitoring in AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avfoundation

In my current project I need very specific control over the AVCaptureDevice and the lighting settings (ISO, exposure,flashMode and even TorchMode). I am not trying to get "high quality" photos, in the sense of typical photography, but it is really important for me to be able to control the settings of the camera precisely, in order to get useable photos.

This poses no problem, as long as I am keeping the flash turned off.
But when setting the flashMode to .on, scene monitoring is enabled in the capturePhoto()-method which determines the flash intensity and auto-focusses while using the torch, even though it is set .off.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput/1778634-photosettingsforscenemonitoring

The flash is required in every photo taken, regardless of lighting conditions. So my question is: Is there a way to avoid scene monitoring and have the capturePhoto() method always using the flash without the torch?

Thanks for your help!